# Not able to deploy a simple JSP web application after build is successfull in a jenkins job

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, tomcat9

I have created a jenkins job to build a simple JSP web application code, after commit to github code repository.
The job is triggerred as soon as a commit happens on the github code repository.
The build is happening successfully, with a snapshot of war file created.
But the post-build actions for deploying the war file on tomcat9 webserver is not happening.

Tried changing the WAR file location with Ant style GLOBs like "**/*.war" 
Also given the path of the war file but it gives an exception.
[image: Deploy to war plugin settings]

Comment: What's the build log's error message?

Comment: Log is not specifying anything after build, although I was able to resolve the issue, the POM.xml file was not in the workspace of the Jenkins project. Hence Jenkins deploy plugin was not able to find war file after build. But it should have generated an error corresponding to that in the log file. Nevertheless, Issue stands closed now.